# Docstring for callable class in Python

Tags: python, docstring

I am trying to document a Python callable class by using docstring so that I can auto-generate documentation in Sphinx.

I am using the [autoDocstring](https://github.com/NilsJPWerner/autoDocstring) plugin for generating docstring stubs.
For classes featuring `__call__` method it seems to format the class description as if it was a function. -It adds `:return:` field in Sphinx docstring.

This makes sense, as then -- when writing code that **uses** an object of this class -- Visual Studio Code shows description of the class rather than its `__call__` method:

[image]

That's fine, but it requires me to document the class as if it was a function.
Of course the intention of objects of callable classes is to behave as functions, but I have the feeling it's not correct for class docstring to have `:return:`.
The `:return:` field obviously shall be in `__call__` method's docstring, as otherwise it may confuse less experienced Python programmers and in such case it is not a clear documentation.

**Questions**:

- Shall I just write the class docstring for callable as if it was a function, keeping the format suggested by autoDocstring plugin?
- Is this an accepted standard for documenting classes with `__call__` method in Python?

Below you will find a sample class used to generate the screenshot above.

```
class MultiplyBy:
"""Functor class for multiplying a number by fixed value

:return: Multiplied value
:rtype: float
"""

def __init__(self, multiplier: float) -> None:
    """Creates multiplier objects

    Multiplier objects may be used to multipliy arbitratry number
    by a fixed multiplier.

    :param multiplier: Fixed multiplier value to be used for multiplying other numbers
    :type multiplier: float
    """

    self.multiplier = multiplier

def __call__(self, value: float) -> float:
    """Multiplies a number by a fixed value

    Returns a number being the value provided multiplied
    by a fixed value specified at the multiplier object construction time.

    :param value: The value to be multiplied
    :type value: float
    :return: The value multiplied by the fixed multiplier
    :rtype: float
    """

    return value * self.multiplier
```

And the code of sample.py

```
from multiplier import MultiplyBy

double = MultiplyBy(2.0)

doubled = double(5.0)
```

Comment: BTW: Is 'functor' the correct name used for Python classes having `__call__` method?

Comment: Functor is a term with various meanings. In functional programming and category theory, it means something completely different from what some C++ programmers have been using it for. `Callable` is probably better terminology. EDIT: I googled and it looks like some python programmers have also started calling it a "functor"... ughh

Comment: Thanks @MateenUlhaq! I changed it. Hope it looks less "ughh" now.